Is there colloquial way to express "X will be aired on TV"?
How can I express "X will be on TV" in daily conversation?
For example, I want to express a movie/football match etc. will be aired on TV starting from 21:00. Are there more colloquial expressions (other than to be aired) I can use like

Today XXX (movie name) will ???? on TV
PSG vs Barcelona will ???? at 9 o'clock tonight.

I suppose to be broadcast or to be aired can be used, but am wondering if that's what people say in daily speech (like talking among families or friends).

Informal:
The game will be on TV at [time]
OR
The game will be shown on TV at [time]
OR
They're showing the game on TV at [time]
Yes, airing or broadcasting is more formal.

And if the context is clear, "TV" might even be omitted: "the game is on at [time]."

yeah sure. eg (for before 2024Apr21 at 8:30am GMT+8)

The 2024 Candidates chess tournament Round 13 will be broadcast on 2024Apr21 at 8:30am GMT+8

or (for before 2024Apr05 at 8:30am GMT+8)

The 2024 Candidates chess tournament will start airing on 2024Apr05 at 8:30am GMT+8

or

The 2024 Candidates chess tournament started airing on 2024Apr05 at 8:30am GMT+8


Please clean up your text. "yeah sure" ain't great for an answer...

I am trying to tell you nicely. But maybe someone else needs to say something. I have zero idea what you just said. Sorry.

None of these suggestions seem colloquial.
